# Aliasing on screen only to eyes. Clean when captured

Tags: display, display-resolution

When I see DDD window in my monitor, (resolution 3840x2160), the menu names are a little blurred (like it's coming from aliasing). But if I capture it with capture program, it is clean. So it is only optical problem. How can I fix this? I don't know when this started. DDD is a display debugger (a gui program, running with gdb inside). I'm using ubuntu 20.04.
See the difference. (The first is using camera so it causes aliasing itself, but when I look at the screen, the menu names are a little blurred).
[image]
[image]

Comment: DDD window in my monitor What is this and what version of Ubuntu?

Comment: DDD is a display debugger (a gui program, running with gdb inside). I'm using ubuntu 20.04.